# Como resolver esse erro? (Ajax Error)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.6

Utilizo um recurso do datatables nesse sistema aqui e toda vez que dou um refresh na página ou após incluir um novo registro, aparece esse erro. Pesquisei bastante, porém ainda sem solução. Testei o sistema em outras máquinas e algumas consigo executar sem erro em outras não. Alguém pode ajudar?

Estou utilizando:

Laravel 5.6, Xampp e o PHP 7.2.3

Aparece esse alert acusando o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inspecionando o código esse tenho esse log:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O erro indica que o Ajax não encontrou o [arquivo requisitado](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7).

Comment: Ciente disso amigo, 404 é não encontrado, porém não consigo solução para esse erro. Em algumas outras máquinas, com o mesmo código fonte consigo executar sem pegar esse erro, na minha não.

Comment: Então o problema está no seu servidor que não acha o arquivo.